# Ad Declation On Google Play Services Shows Admob Within APK

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, codenameone

Google Play now require you to fill out an Ad Declaration for all apps distributed through Google Play. I updated my apps to "Not ad supported" and Google responded that it found an ad SDK in my app, AdMob 350.

They accepted the no ad declaration even with that there so it is not essential, but is there a way to exclude that from the build as I am not using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codename One includes Google Play Services by default in builds since 3.2.

Play services include many nice features such as improved location, IAP etc. they also ship with admob integrated.

You can remove google play services from inclusion by setting the `android.includeGPlayServices=false` build hint.

Comment: *Codename One includes Google Play Services by default* that is an unbelievably bad feature

Comment: Why? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Because it is an immensely huge library. If you have a big app and you include the entire play services library you are almost guaranteed to exceed the limit of 65k methods, and then you'll get errors. It is better to only include the parts of the library that you are actually using in your app

Comment: We obfuscate everything by default too so it reduces some of the size. If a developer wants to remove the library he can as explained above. We have some pretty huge apps that do need the multidex flag but those are indeed huge. Not all of GPS is included only the important/relevant ones.

Comment: Alright, I trust you know what you're doing, since it's your platform

Comment: Thanks for the headsup though. Its always good knowing someone is checking!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the entire google play service as a dependency in your app.

> From Google Play Services version 6.5 and beyond you can select which
>   individual APIs you want to use, and import just those ones.

This is the entire list

```
Google+                         com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:6.5.+
Google Account Login            com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:6.5.+
Google Activity Recognition     com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.+
Google App Indexing             com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:6.5.+
Google Cast                     com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:6.5.+
Google Drive                    com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:6.5.+
Google Fit                      com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:6.5.+
Google Maps                     com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.+
Google Mobile Ads               com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.+
Google Panorama Viewer          com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:6.5.+
Google Play Game services       com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:6.5.+
Google Wallet                   com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:6.5.+
Android Wear                    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+
Google Actions
Google Analytics
Google Cloud Messaging          com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+
```

[Source of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27675427/1957401)

So i guess if you add these after remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` (and others that you dont need) instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services` (the whole bunch) you should be able to get rid of the admob related stuff (and other unwanted stuff).

Comment: The assumption is incorrect. See the discussion in the other answer. We don't currently expose the fine grained control as a build hint but that will probably be available in an upcoming update.

Comment: @Virus assumption is correct. You **DO** have the entire GooglePlayServices library as a dependency in your app. It is a transitive dependency via Codename